# Create account - wordpress says email already exists

Tags: account

My wife wants to create a WordPress account, but she can’t do this because the website says she has already an account.

We thought perhaps she has forgotten the password and so she tried to resend the password... 
 WordPress says the email address doesn't exist...

Strange she now cant do anything anymore. She searched in her mail but didn't find WordPress login.

What I am trying to find out is how can she register?

Comment: Do you have access with another account to the dashboard?  if not, do you have ftp access or db access?

Comment: Sounds like you are using wordpress.com. If it is the case, then this is definitely a question to ask their support, as no one here will be able to help.